# Modifying specific subelements of similar elements in XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using Python and `ElementTree` to attempt to modify `XML` files, but having difficulty with modifying only some elements and not all elements. The difficulty arises as each element is structured extremely similarly. Here's a sample:

```
    <data>
    <Property name="Table">
        <Property value="GenericEntry">
            <Property name="Type" value="GenericType">
                <Property name="InteractionType" value="NPC" />
            </Property>
            <Property name="Options">
              <Property value="OptionTable">
                <Property name="Rewards">
                  <Property value="StringSample">
                    <Property name="Value" value="Whatever" />
                  </Property>
                </Property>
              </Property>
            </Property>
        </Property>
       <Property value="GenericEntry">
            <Property name="Type" value="GenericType">
                <Property name="InteractionType" value="Frog" />
            </Property>
            <Property name="Options">
              <Property value="OptionTable">
                <Property name="Rewards">
                  <Property value="StringSample">
                    <Property name="Value" value="Whatever" />
                  </Property>
                </Property>
              </Property>
            </Property>
        </Property>
        <Property value="GenericEntry">
            <Property name="Type" value="GenericType">
                <Property name="InteractionType" value="NPC" />
            </Property>
            <Property name="Options">
              <Property value="OptionTable">
                <Property name="Rewards">
                  <Property value="StringSample">
                    <Property name="Value" value="Whatever" />
                  </Property>
                </Property>
              </Property>
            </Property>
        </Property>
    </Property>
  </data>
```

I'm attempting to add a subelement to an arbitrary number of GenericEntries that *only* have the NPC type involved, specifically under Rewards. However, at the moment, I've only been able to sort out how to add subelements to all the GenericEntries, regardless of type.

Here's the code I've put together so far:

```
for glance in root.findall("./Property/Property"):
    see = glance.find(".//Property[@name='InteractionType']").get('value')
    if see == "NPC": #Obviously not the right track...
    for gah in root.findall("./Property/Property/Property[@name='Options']"):
        aha = gah.find("./Property/Property[@name='Rewards']")
        here = ET.SubElement(aha, "Property", value='StringSample')
        there = ET.SubElement(here, "Property", name='Value', value='Boop')
```

I've attempted to narrow the findall/find methods as I worked through this, but kept hitting blocks where I was being far too specific for it to be more broadly extensible for arbitrary amounts of entries. However, it seems I've overcorrected.

In short, the aim is to rewrite this to identify certain entry types and modify multiple entries of those specified types via adding subelements to them.

Expected output would look like this:

```
    <data>
    <Property name="Table">
        <Property value="GenericEntry">
            <Property name="Type" value="GenericType">
                <Property name="InteractionType" value="NPC" />
            </Property>
            <Property name="Options">
              <Property value="OptionTable">
                <Property name="Rewards">
                  <Property value="StringSample">
                    <Property name="Value" value="Whatever" />
                  </Property>
                  <Property value="StringSample">
                    <Property name="Value" value="Boop" />
                  </Property>
                </Property>
              </Property>
            </Property>
        </Property>
       <Property value="GenericEntry">
            <Property name="Type" value="GenericType">
                <Property name="InteractionType" value="Frog" />
            </Property>
            <Property name="Options">
              <Property value="OptionTable">
                <Property name="Rewards">
                  <Property value="StringSample">
                    <Property name="Value" value="Whatever" />
                  </Property>
                </Property>
              </Property>
            </Property>
        </Property>
        <Property value="GenericEntry">
            <Property name="Type" value="GenericType">
                <Property name="InteractionType" value="NPC" />
            </Property>
            <Property name="Options">
              <Property value="OptionTable">
                <Property name="Rewards">
                  <Property value="StringSample">
                    <Property name="Value" value="Whatever" />
                  </Property>
                  <Property value="StringSample">
                    <Property name="Value" value="Boop" />
                  </Property>
                </Property>
              </Property>
            </Property>
        </Property>
    </Property>
  </data>
```

Comment: there's no `<Property>` item *under StringSample* with `value="NPC"` in your input. Besides, post the expected output

Comment: Good catch, my mistake on output and light clarity issues. Added expected output, which should better indicate what I'm seeking to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
# select Property's with specific value, move to parent's parent (/../.. = <Property value="GenericEntry">)
for gah in root.findall('.//Property[@name="InteractionType"][@value="NPC"]/../..'):
    aha = gah.find('.//Property[@name="Rewards"]')
    here = ET.SubElement(aha, "Property", value='StringSample')
    there = ET.SubElement(here, "Property", name='Value', value='Boop')
```